# Get Week Day Name for the first of the month from an NSDate

Tags: xcode, cocoa, date, components, weekday

I have an NSDate and I want to find out the Week Day Name for the FIRST of the month from that NSDate. So for example I get given "15th of May 2013" and I want to return "Wednesday" as "1st of May 2013" was a Wednesday. Here is my test code;

```
    // Setup a Date and Formatter and load with a date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-05-10"];
    NSLog(@"Day In Month : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

    // Setup a calendar and extract components and force to the first
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    //NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [dateComponants setDay:1];

    date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponants];
    NSLog(@"First Day : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

    // Change the formatter for the Day name
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSLog(@"Day Name : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

And here is what my log says....

```
Day In Month : 2013-05-10
First Day : 2013-06-01
Day Name : Saturday
```

What is the June date doing in the middle?  In fact the 1st of June is a Saturday but that does not really help me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

with

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: date];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot of the highest degree!!!!

```
    NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Should be

```
    NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
```

Been looking at it for an hour...

Comment: Haha aren't they both the same?

Comment: Yep did it again (changed now), may give this one up for the day.